# Exporting Firestore collection data, edit and re-upload

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I created a Google Cloud account and have everything setup but for some reason I can't figure out how to export my Firestore data to a "file" edit/add to that file and re-upload.

I'm read through this several times:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#import_specific_collections

No code but just real confusion. I am not sure how to export a collection so that I can make bulk edits.

Comment: Did you find a solution to edit the exported data?

Comment: Were you able to find solution for editing the data after exporting firestore data in cloud storage bucket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use gcloud cli to [export](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_all_documents) to a cloud store bucket

```
gcloud beta firestore export gs://[BUCKET_NAME]
```

To export to a local file, you can use the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases)

```
POST https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1beta1/{name=projects/*/databases/*}:exportDocuments
```

There is also an npm app which can do this, [node-firestore-import-export](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-firestore-import-export).

```
firestore-export --accountCredentials path/to/credentials/file.json --backupFile /backups/myDatabase.json
```

```
firestore-import --accountCredentials path/to/credentials/file.json --backupFile /backups/myDatabase.json
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on the second option? I think it might not work according to the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/reference/rest/v1beta1/projects.databases/exportDocuments

Comment: I had used the npm app previously, and it worked. I exported and imported using the same tool for each collection separately. I had to split the exports by collection instead of the whole DB because importing fails due to the batch ops that can be performed had limits and threw some error. I haven't tried this recently to know if anything changed.