# Exporting firebase data to json

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, gcloud

I'm trying to export a particular Firestore collection using `gcloud`
Right now, I did

```
gcloud storage buckets create gs://my-bucket 
gcloud firestore export gs://my-bucket --collection-ids=my-collection 
gcloud storage cp -r gs://my-bucket/2022-09-22T09:20:16_11252 my-directory
```

which results in some content in `my-directory/all_namespaces/.../output-1`.  The `output-1` file definitely seems to contain some relevant data but it is not very readable.  Hence some questions:

- which file format is used?
- can I export to JSON (or CSV or XML) directly
- can I convert the current file to JSON, CSV or XML

And related

- why is `output-0` empty?

Comment: The export format is documented [Export format and metadata files](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_format_and_metadata_files) (LevelDB log format)

Comment: Here is how to export to json https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70899359/how-to-export-data-from-cloud-firestore-to-file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Surprisingly, there don't seem to be a lot of LevelDB tools available so exporting to LevelDB format is not convenient.

I managed to export to csv by adding two extra steps: loading and extracting to/from BigQuery.  So I now do something like

```
# create bucket
gcloud storage buckets create gs://my-bucket 

# firestore export
gcloud firestore export gs://my-bucket/my-prefix --collection-ids=my-collection 

# create dataset
bq mk --dataset my_dataset

# load bucket into BigQuery
bq load --replace --source_format=DATASTORE_BACKUP my_dataset.input \
gs://my-bucket/my-prefix/all_namespaces/.../....export_metadata

# export BigQuery as csv to bucket
bq extract --compression GZIP 'my_dataset.input' gc://my-bucket/results.csv

# download csv file
gcloud storage cp -r gc://my-bucket/results.csv <local-dir>
```

Comment: This is a perfect answer. But if you are getting an "Unexpected entity" error watch out for these gotchas mentioned here https://stackoverflow.com/a/56841619

Answer (score 2):

Firestore does not support exporting existing data to a readable file but Firestore do have a managed Exporting and importing data that allows you to dump your data into a GCS bucket. It produces a format that is the same as Cloud Datastore uses. This means you can then import it into BigQuery. You can refer to this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70899359/how-to-export-data-from-cloud-firestore-to-file) and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3J1M1bSwgV8)

Also as mentioned above in comment by Dazwilkin, The output of a managed export uses the [LevelDB log format](https://github.com/google/leveldb/blob/master/doc/log_format.md).

Additionally you can have a look at this [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66154067/how-can-i-export-my-firestore-database-from-a-google-storage-bucket-into-a-json) & [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54382332/exporting-firestore-collection-data-edit-and-re-upload)

Comment: I already did an export to a GCS bucket.  But I wanted to download this bucket and use the data.  The LevelDB format seems to lack some tooling so I added an addition load/export to BigQuery to get it converted to csv

Comment: As usual with GCP everything is only done to the absolute MVP. Having a json export for a json based database seems like a no brainer but not with Google apparently... Can't believe that this still is missing after half a decade.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can export firebase data as json, follow this article for exporting the data from firebase I hope this helps - https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6386780?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Comment: I'm not sure but I think this answer refers to Firebase Realtime database, not to a Firestore database.  I don't see the "export JSON" menu entry.